# how does setEnterTransition() and setExitTransition() method of fragments works?

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment



setEnterTransition(new Slide(Gravity.END));
setExitTransition(new Slide((Gravity.END));
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, container, false);
}
```

i have tried this two methods in my fragments to set animation in viewpager but it doesn't work .

Answer (score 2):

See it :

```
 1.setExitTransition() - A’s exit transition animates transitioning views out of the scene when A starts B.

 2.setEnterTransition() - B’s enter transition animates transitioning views into the scene when A starts B.
```

Comment: okay i understood but what if i want to give  different enter and exit transition to fragments  individually ? which transition will perform at the time of one's exit and another's entry?